# How to construct a class with an existing base class pointer?

Tags: c++

I have one base class and two derived child's (different classes).

I would like to construct one child and then construct a second child which uses the same base class instance like the first child.

In pseudo code this would look like this:

```
class Parent
{
public: 
    int x;
};

class ChildA : public Parent
{
    void setX() {x=5;}
};

class ChildB : public Parent
{
    int getX() {return x;} //Shall return 5 after calling the set method of ChildA first
};


//Creating instances
ChildA* a;
a = new ChildA();

Parent* ptrToBaseClass = a;

ChildB* b;
b = new ChildB(); //How can I set this to the same base class ptr (Parent*) which instance “a” has?
```

How can this be achieved with passing the base class pointer?

Comment: You can copy the base properties from one to the other but only once, you can't have reference semantics if that's what you want

Comment: When an instance of `ChildA` calls `setX()` only the member `x` of that instance gets the value 5. The member `x` of this particular instance is not known to any other instance of the class `ChildA`, or instances of `Parent` or of `ChildB`.

Comment: If it is only about `int x;`, make it static. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: The short answer is "you can't".   A `ChildB` has no relationship to a `ChildA`. and each object you have created (`a` and `b`) effectively inherits from a different instance of the base `Parent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to construct one child and then construct a second child which uses the same base class instance like the first child.

What you would like is not possible. Each base class sub object is stored within the most derived object.

You can use the existing base to copy initialise the base of another object, but they will be separate.

---

What you could do to achieve something similar, is to use indirection:

```
struct Parent
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> x = std::make_shared<int>();
};

struct ChildA : Parent
{
    void setX() {*x=5;}
};

struct ChildB : Parent
{
    int getX() {return *x;} //Shall return 5 after calling the set method of ChildA first
};

int main() {
    ChildA a;
    Parent& a_base = a;
    ChildB b {a_base}; // note that the base is copied here
    a.setX();
    std::cout << b.getX();
}
```

This way even though the base objects are separate, they both refer to shared state.

A simpler solution is to store the state in static storage (such as static member, as suggested by [Ahmet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57310877/2079303)). But this will make the state shared across all instances while the indirection allows exact control over which objects share which state.

Comment: It is possible with Static variables.

Comment: @AhmetIpkin A static variable won't make the base object shared; only the static member is shared. And it will be shared across all instances; not just those two in the example.

Comment: If the whole `Base` class is to be shared, then one can use [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance). This is still possible.

Comment: @AhmetIpkin virtual inheritance shares the base class of an object with other base classes of this class's subclass. Not even remotely the same thing

Comment: @ayxan not directly same, but similar can be achieved. Super hacky though.

Comment: Is this aggregate initialization fine with inheritance?

Comment: @Ayxan It's list-initialisation, and it's fine.

Comment: @eerorika I see that you edited it to use a cast. Was the previous version fine too?

Comment: @Ayxan yeah it was fine too. I changed to initialise the base itself rather than just the member in order to be closer to the original example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Copying the state of the base when constructing the second child is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `x` in `Parent` class `static`. This will allow you to do this - although I have to warn you that this is quite a dodgy code and can bite you in the a**.

Of course, then you have to access it with rather than just `x`; as `Parent::x`.

EDIT: I seem to got it wrong. If you want the whole base class as 'shared' rather than just `x`; you need pointers and custom logic to manage it - there is no direct language construct.

Comment: That means the *member* is shared, not the base class instance. And it means the member will be shared over *all* instances of the class, not just the two instances the OP wanted to have share the base class instance.

Comment: This solves nothing. It should have been a comment as a suggestion since it doesn't address the question directly